# have a join query which i need to optimize using OR and Stats, i am new to splunk and i am confused how to start

Tags: query-optimization, splunk, splunk-query

`index="index1" sourcetype=sourcetype1 | join commonfield [ search <br>index="index2" sourcetype=sourcetype2 ] | sort _time | stats <br>last(index1field1) as state by index2field1, index1field2, index1field3 <br>| where index1field1 != "UP" | dedup index2field1 | stats count`

I want to optimize this query without join using stats and OR, can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sure. next time i will keep in mind. Any hints for this question?

Answer (score 0):

```
(index="index1" sourcetype=sourcetype1) OR (index="index2" sourcetype=sourcetype2)
| stats values(*) AS *, values(_*) as * by commonfield
```

This will be a fairly good starting point. Bring in both sets of data initially, then merge all the fields from both sources, "joining" based on the `commonfield`